# What does '-' mean in a Shell script?

Tags: linux, cut, options

I'm trying to understand a script I have and it has a line that says

```
cut -d '-' -f 1
```

I don't understand what '-' does here

Comment: For future reference, "what does X mean in a shell script" is entirely dependent on the context of "X". In this case, it's the argument for an option to `cut`. In other circumstances it could be a different command or some builtin shell syntax. Next time you have this question, have a look at the documentation for the particular command (e.g. `man cut`) -- being able to self-troubleshoot will save your own time.

Answer (score 2):

The `cut` command's `-d` option allows you to specify a field delimiter, so this will `cut` the `1`<sup>st</sup> `-`-`d`elimited `f`ield.

```
$ echo 'foo-bar-baz' | cut -d '-' -f 1
foo
```

Quoting was used around the `-` character presumably to make sure the character is not interpreted specially by the shell or possibly for coding style considerations. However it's not necessary as `-` has no special role in the syntax of any shell¹ so you can also use `cut -d - -f 1` or even `cut -d- -f1` here.

see `man cut`

[cut(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)

---

<sup>¹ Thankfully! It would be awkward if we had to type `ls '-l' '-a'` for instance or `cut '-d' '-' '-f' 1` here.</sup>